# Text not working in A-Frame 1.4.0 VR mode

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to make a VR application for the browser & cardboard. I'm trying to show up some text, but every time I go to the VR mode, I just can't see it. I see the text in 3D mode, but once I click on the cardboard mode, all the text just disappears. I've tried a previous version (0.9.2) of A-Frame and it seems to work just fine. You can just copy and paste the [example code](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/components/text.html#example) from the documentation and it would not work.

Now to my setup:

- I have a local server (XAMPP), where I host all my files (including `aframe.min.js`)
- I am using the 1.4.0 version of A-Frame
- I use an iPhone 12 Mini and Safari 16 as my browser

The exact code that I've added:

```
<a-entity text="value: Hello World;"  rotation="0 90 0" position="-8 5.6 -4" scale="13 13 13"></a-entity>
```

Here's an [example code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/skitter-psychedelic-brie?path=index.html%3A1%3A0) where this problem is highlighted. You will have to access it with a mobile device, then click on the VR mode to actually see the problem.

Comment: I recommend sharing full runnable example to reproduce. It's working for me https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nifty-aquamarine-dugong?path=index.html%3A7%3A13

Comment: I've added an example and I've tried it on my iPhone and it's not working. I've just added the VR mode option to your example.